# Your order is "ready to be delivered" or "ready to be shipped"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

English is my second language and I need some help.
I was wondering which of these sentences applied better to a store that is sending a product to their customers. Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: Hello, Luiza, and welcome to the ELL. Can you give an explicit context (a full sentence or a short dialogue),where you would use this phrase? Context always helps to narrow down the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have very similar meanings, and can largely be used interchangeably.

However, "ready to be shipped" means that the item is still in YOUR warehouse, whereas "ready to be delivered" might be taken to mean that the item is in the hands of the courier, possibly even 'out for delivery'. Depending on locations and delivery methods, that may not mean much, or it could be a difference of a week or so.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mike!